# Verbatim Tag inside IF statement

Tags: angularjs, symfony, twig, verbatim

I am new to Twig and AngularJS. So, please be easy on me. Here is the case, I read it somewhere that if statement in Twig only works outside verbatim tag. So, that's why I `endverbatim` right before the if statement block. However, **I need to turn verbatim on again to get that "something" value inside the if statement**. So the logic is kinda like this:

```
{% verbatim %}
   some code here...
   {% endverbatim %}
   {% if (turn on verbatim) something (turn off verbatim) == false %} ... {% endif %}
   {% verbatim %}   

{% endverbatim %}
```

Is it possible? or is there any other approach for this problem? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Did you try putting the `{% endif %}` after the `{% endverbatim %}`. I'm no expert on either, but that sounds like it should work to me.

Like so:

```
{% if something == false %}
    {% verbatim %}   
    ...
    {% endverbatim %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: hey, sorry that not i was looking for. I've edited my question above. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no such syntax like turn on or off verbatim. But you can start and end your raw code block with `{% verbatim %}` and `{% endverbatim %}` any time. Like for your example code should be like follow if you just need to echo your value of the `something` variable:

```
{% verbatim %}
some code here...

{% if ( {% endverbatim %} {{  something  }}{% verbatim %}) == false %} .... {% endif %}
{% endverbatim %}

{% endverbatim %}
```

This will output

```
some code here...

{% if ( value of your something ) == false %} .. {% endif %}
```

### **Update**

If you are using AngularJs template, I am not sure about your `{% if (turn on verbatim) something (turn off verbatim) == false %} ... {% endif %}`  part. I could not find such syntax in angularJs docs. if you problem is relate to using angularJs within twig, I'll suggest you read [this](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/%24interpolateProvider). If you are interested to play with twig you can find something [here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#registering-a-new-tag). And [here is the docs for AngularJs ngif directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)

Happy coding!

Comment: Out of curiosity, what kind of an abomination of a language is that? That's probably the most verbose, hard to read code I've ever seen. Even C++ is more readable.

Comment: @JesseBrands: Its a syntax for template engine. Actually here is syntax for two template engine with some similar syntax. From tags I can say, one of them is [twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) and another is [angularjs](http://angularjs.org/). [verbatim](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/verbatim.html) is a tag of twig which help to output raw code instead of parsing it as twig.